# Traveling to Costa Rica

Tags: customs-and-immigration, costa-rica

I only have a carry on no checked baggage. I will be landing in San Jose on Spirit Airlines but catching a connecting flight on Sensa over to the East Coast Caribbean side. Do I go through customs in San Jose or do I just get the connecting flight and go through customs in the Limon Airport in Costa Rica my final destination?

Comment: Thanks for the edits. When and where do I find the answers to my question?

Comment: I would think that if you had to leave the San Jose airport and you are not a citizen of Costa Rica, you would have have to go through customs at San Jose.

Answer (score 3):

Sansa flies out of a separate building, not the International Terminal.  So yes, you would need to clear immigration and customs in San Jose.